# dump() for environments (recursively)

Tags: r, serialization

I want to `dump()` some objects, but unfortunately `dump()` isn't robust enough:

```
x = 5
# ok
dump('x', stdout())
# x <-
# 5

# bad / incomplete
dump('.GlobalEnv', stdout())
# .GlobalEnv <-
```

> Error in dump(".GlobalEnv", stdout()) : 
>     (converted from warning) deparse may be incomplete

In the simple case, this can be overcome with `dump` itself:

```
# option 1; can be reversed by wrapping in
#   list2env(within(list(), { . }))
e = new.env()
e$x = 5
dump(ls(e), stdout(), envir = e)
# x <-
# 5

# option 2; can be reversed by wrapping in 
#   list2env( . )
e = as.list(e)
dump('e', stdout())
```

However, this falls apart in nested scenarios:

```
l = list(e = new.env())
l$e$x = 5
# same error as before
dump('l', stdout())
```

The desired output in this case would be anything that could reproduce `l` with `source`, e.g.

```
l <-
list(e = list2env(within(list(), {
  x <- 
  5
})))
```

It's a recursive problem but I'm a bit stuck on how to go about it exactly.

There's also the hairy issue that environments can be truly recursive (environment `e` contains `e` itself); I would ignore this for the purposes here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For now, I've managed to solve the problem laterally by using `save()` to output the objects instead of `dput()`/`dump()`. As `save()` doesn't have an `append` option, I made the following workaround:

```
TARGET = tempfile()

repro_env = new.env()
if (file.exists(TARGET)) {
  load(TARGET, envir = repro_env)
  repro_env$obj_count = repro_env$obj_count + 1L
} else repro_env$obj_count = 1L
repro_env[[sprintf('object_%d', repro_env$obj_count)]] = object
save(list = ls(repro_env), envir = repro_env, file = TARGET)
```

Then when I need to, I can `load(TARGET)` to get the complete objects back in any other R session.